# Update a specific field in elastic search document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to update a document in elasticsearch,but instead the document gets deleted

```
POST /index/type/id/
{
   "id":1
   "field:"modified"
}
```

What is the way to update a particular field in a document?The document contains an id field by which it is indexed.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html - Take a look at Scripted Updates.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend reading the elastic search documentation about [partial updates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html).

> The simplest form of the update request accepts a partial document as the doc parameter, which just gets merged with the existing document.
>
> Objects are merged together, existing scalar fields are overwritten, and new fields are added.

In your situation, I would use the following aproach:

```
POST /index/type/id/_update
{
    "doc": {
        "id": 1
        "field: "modified"
    }
}
```

But please keep in mind that this will only modify the id field from inside the document, the document _id will not be modified. If you want to modify the document _id, you will have to delete the current document and create a new one with the id you require.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing.
Export your Elastic search in a file format using the below commands.

```
sudo npm install elasticsearch-tools -g



es-export-bulk --url http://localhost:9200 --file ~/Desktop/filename.json --index elastic_collection_name
```

Then open that file and update all the data you want..
Then using the below command import it.

```
es-import-bulk --url http://localhost:9200 --file ~/Desktop/filename.json
```

Try it.